# Django render is very slow

Tags: python, django

This is my training django project. I am using GeoIP, django-modeltranslation, i18n. Showing video gallery page is very slow. The database contains about 20 entries.

Model

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from datetime import datetime
import urllib, json, re
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Video(models.Model):
  class Meta:
  abstract = True

  title = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
  text = RichTextUploadingField()
  link = models.CharField(max_length=80)
  slug = models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=40,blank=True,null=True)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  position = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  meta = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

  class VideoMessage(Video):
    class Meta:
      verbose_name = _('VideoMessage')
      verbose_name_plural = _('VideoMessages')
```

Translation

```
from modeltranslation.translator import translator, TranslationOptions
from models import VideoMessage

class VideoMessageTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
  fields = ('text', 'link', 'meta',)

translator.register(VideoMessage, VideoMessageTranslationOptions)
```

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from models import VideoMessage

class Index(View):
  def get(self, request):
    params={}
    messages=VideoMessage.objects.exclude(is_active=False).exclude(link='').order_by('-position')
    params['videos']={}
    params['videos']['message']=messages
    return render(request, 'index.html', params)
```

[gprof2dot tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEChk.png) 100% = ~2000ms

Comment: Pagination maybe? Where is the time taken? rendering the template or the database queries?

Comment: Pagination for 20 elements? [tree.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VEChk.png) I think template rendering..

Comment: install [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and check what's happening.

Comment: If its a problem with rendering the template then it might help to see what that template is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I parsed the image at each rendering. It was bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out what takes the longest time. 
You can use something like [Opbeat](http://opbeat.com) where you can get a free account. You can see a breakdown on what takes time on different requests so you can focus on whatever is slow.

Also, is this happening only during development or also in production? Having `DEBUG=True` in a production setup is not only a bad idea but also it can have a big impact on performance.